# System tables and APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

could you tell me how I can find out which system tables store information about the tables accessed by the APEX?
I have the APEX version 20.2
Where can such information be located
SYS, SYSTEM or the APEX 200200?

Comment: I'd say exactly there, in Apex schema (in your case, user APEX_200200).

Comment: What tables are you talking about?  Are you asking what tables the APEX system itself uses?  Or are you trying to figure out which tables a particular APEX application uses?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, i need tables which a particular APEX application uses